# InputMismatchException while inputting multiple lines into ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, import, inputmismatchexception

While putting a .txt file into a list I keep running into a InputMismatchException error. That won't read the "MovieType" or "AlbumTitle". Relevant code has been added.

```
public class MovieManager {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        ArrayList<MediaItem> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(new File("collection.txt"));
        try {
            while (inputFile.hasNextLine()){
                String mediaType = inputFile.nextLine();
                if (mediaType.equals("Movie")){
                    String movieTitle = inputFile.nextLine();
                    //System.out.println("String" + movieTitle);
                    int movieYear = inputFile.nextInt();
                    //System.out.println("int" + movieYear);
                    String movieType = inputFile.nextLine();
                    //System.out.println("String" + movieType);
                    Movie mov = new Movie(movieTitle, movieYear, movieType);
                    list.add(mov);
                } else if (mediaType.equals("Album")) {
                    String albumArtist = inputFile.nextLine();
                    //System.out.println("String" + albumArtist);
                    int albumYear = inputFile.nextInt();
                    //System.out.println("int" + albumYear);
                    String albumTitle = inputFile.nextLine();
                    //System.out.println("String" + albumTitle);
                    Album alb = new Album(albumArtist, albumYear, albumTitle);
                    list.add(alb);
               }
            }
            inputFile.close();
            System.out.print(list);
        } catch(InputMismatchException e) {
           inputFile.next();
        }
    }
}
```

Collection.txt

```
Album
ABBA
1976
Arrival
Album
ABBA
1981 
The Visitors
Album
The Beatles
1969
Abbey Road
Album
Nazareth
1975
Hair of the Dog
Movie
Beauty and the Beast
1991
VHS
Movie
It's a Wonderful Life
1946
DVD
Movie
Tron
1983
Laserdisc
Movie
Tron: Legacy
2010
Blu-ray
```

Comment: You've got a lot of `println()`'s in your code - how far did the code get?

Comment: It printed everything down to the last line. But skipped the AlbumTitle and MovieType.

Comment: So then you must not be getting an `InputMismatchException`, are you?

Comment: What happens if `mediaType.equals("Movie")` and `mediaType.equals("Album")` both return `false`?  If you can answer that, you should have a big clue as to where your problem lies.

Comment: Not since i added the try catch. The only thing outputting now is  `[moviemanager.Album@3d4eac69, moviemanager.Album@42a57993, moviemanager.Album@75b84c92, moviemanager.Album@6bc7c054, moviemanager.Movie@232204a1, moviemanager.Movie@4aa298b7, moviemanager.Movie@7d4991ad, moviemanager.Movie@28d93b30]`

Comment: Nope!  You're `try ... catch ...` would just capture the error and then exit.  It is not inside the loop, so it wouldn't keep reading anything.  Try again.

Comment: I took out the try catch and it did not throw any errors. And add an else to see what would happen and it is choosing that as many times its skipping `albumTitle` and `movieType`

Comment: I honestly have no clue what could be making it skip those lines.

Comment: Your input is `... ABBA \n 1976 \n Arrival \n ...`.  The `movieTitle = nextLine()` consumes `ABBA \n` and return "ABBA".  The `movieYear = nextInt()` call just consumes `1976`, and leaves `\n Arrival \n ...` in the input stream.  Then, `movieType = nextLine()` consumes the `\n` and returns "", leaving `Arrival \n ...`.  Finally, `mediaType = nextLine()` consumes the `Arrival \n`, which it didn't know what to do with, looped around, called it again, and got a real media type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With an input stream containing `1976\n`, a call to `Scanner#nextInt()` will consume only the digit characters.  It leaves the `\n` newline character in the input stream, for the next call to a `Scanner` method to deal with.

The subsequent call to `Scanner#nextLine()` immediately sees the `\n`, character, and consumes it, and returns the empty string, because after the digits `1976` to the end of the line was the empty string.

Or, visualized another way...  nextLine(), nextInt(), nextLine() parses:

```
ABBA \n 1976 \n Arrival \n
```

as:

```
[ABBA\n][1976][\n]
```

returning:

```
"ABBA"   1976  ""
```

Solution:

> You need to discard the remainder of the "year" line, after calling `nextInt()`, by immediately calling `nextLine()`, and ignoring the returned value.